# brushless motor as a servo

Tags: arduino, brushless-motor

I would like to use(or control) a gimbal brushless motor like a servo meaning I want to control position not rotation speed. The position must be from 0 to 180 and 0 to -180 
I will use an Arduino board. And I think a ESC board 
Can I use PWM control offered by servo library? Is it possible?
Have someone any idea 
a) If is possible to do what I want?
b) Orientation(guideline) about library usage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want it to hold position? .... what will you use for position feedback? .... how much time do you have available for developing the system?

Comment: Yes, I want to hold position. Its not a project.Its my own interest, an idea.

Comment: Sorry, I sent by error. I want to hold position. I did not think about feed back , like servos , but its true servos has potenciometer to feedback position

Comment: you would need at least a system that is similar to a hobby servo ... you could make it quite sophisticated and use a control system that is similar to a quadcopter   ............   google `PID controller`

Comment: You might find it easier to use a system that communicates with a serial protocol to the motor to tell it the exact position and speed profile that you want. You'd use a small microcontroller to handle this computing to turn it into the PWM for the motor controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you need something reading the position of the shaft, since a brushless motor is unaware of its own state. You can use potentiometers, incremental encoders, and absolute angle encoders to reach some approximate reading of the state. Then, you would need a PID controller that accepts desired state as input and as output sends current to the motor based on the error between the desired state and the actual state.